How to create Azure Devops Service Connection Docker Registry Type Other
I need help to create correctly an Azure Devops Service Connection for an Azure Container Registry (ACR) but I have only username and password to login.
I have created the credential with this script:
#!/bin/bash
ACR_NAME=MYACRNAME
SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME=MYACRNAME_PUSH

ACR_REGISTRY_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --query "id" --output tsv)

PASSWORD=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --scopes $ACR_REGISTRY_ID --role acrpush --query "password" --output tsv)
USER_NAME=$(az ad sp list --display-name $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --query "[].appId" --output tsv)

echo "Service principal ID: $USER_NAME"
echo "Service principal password: $PASSWORD"

So I eneded up to create the service connection like the image below. I'm pretty sure my credential are valid but when I tried to run the Docker@2 task I have always the same error:
unauthorized: {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}]} 


The pipeline template that uses Docker@2 task is defined.
It is important to say that the login step is successful but the push step fails
parameters:
- name: docker
  type: object
  default:
    repository: ""
    tag: ""
    registry: ""

steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Registry Login
  continueOnError: false
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.docker.registry }}

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push Image
  continueOnError: false
  inputs:
    command: push
    repository: ${{ parameters.docker.repository }}
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.docker.registry }}
    tags: ${{ parameters.docker.tag }}


Can you confirm where the user and password are generated? Are you using ACR tokens (ACR -> Repository Permissions -> Tokens)to generate name and password? Or use the admin user from Access keys.

@KevinLu-MSFT the user/password are generated as az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --scopes $ACR_REGISTRY_ID --role acrpush --query "password" --output tsv

@KevinLu-MSFT I have tried locally with the docker cli and I'm able to login and push successfully

Can you try to use Service Principal Application ID(Client ID)( Navigate to AAD -> App registrations -> Target Service Principal -> Application ID) to fill in the docker ID field in Service connection and check if it can work?

@KevinLu-MSFT sorry for misleading you, I'm already using the Client ID, I changed it in the screenshot with the string "testuser". To be clear, I retrieve the Client ID with the command az ad sp list --display-name $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --query "[].appId" --output tsv

@KevinLu-MSFT I have updated the screenshot posted in the question too

@KevinLu-MSFT I'll try to double check but... the response is UNAUTHORIZED, if there was a network problem shouldn't have I a different error?

Based on the updated screenshot in question, I can confirm that the service connection should be correct. So I want to check the docker definition and some other settings in docker registry

@KevinLu-MSFT the ACR I'm working on has Pricing Plan: Standard, only Premium Plan can enable the firewall. The Public network access is set to "All networks"

@KevinLu-MSFT I have updated again my question with the source script used to create the credentials

At the same time, I have tested the script you shared in the question to generate password and username again. And after I input the id and password to service connection. It can push the image to ACR without issue.  So you can also consider re-running the script again and use the new credential to create a new service connection to check if it can make some changes.

@KevinLu-MSFT I have added the definition of the docker task used to push the image. It is important to say that the login step is successful but the push step fails

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have checked all information you shared. I notice that the ACR name is Uppercase in local command. But we need to use lowercase ACR URL in service connection. Please refer to my updated answer.

Hi @KevinLu-MSFT, I have doublechecked creating the service connection specifying the ACR name in the url lowercase and uppercase (https://MYACRREPO.azurecr.io/ vs https://myacrrepo.azurecr.io). the service connection works only with the lowercase!!!

@KevinLu-MSFT, given that the question has been rightfully closed, what do you think, could we move it on another stackoverflow site?

Glad to know that the issue has been resolved. I think this is a question that fits the Azure DevOps and Azure Pipelines tag in this SO site.  We may also consider reopening it. This question should be helpful to other users who have the same issue.

@KevinLu-MSFT I agree with you, I spent few days trying to figure out how to create successfully a service connection with type "other". I think this post (question/answer) is very valuable, we have only find the right "home".

@KevinLu-MSFT I have voted for reopen

yeah. I have voted too

Update:
Based on the comments above, you have input the Service Principal Application ID to the Docker ID field.
And the same service principal can work on your local machine with the command: docker push MYACRREPO.azurecr.io/branking:1.0.1.

It is important to say that the login step is successful but the push step fails

I can reproduce the same situation.

The cause of the issue can be that you need to use lowercase ACR name in the service connection.
For example:

Pushing Docker images to ACR using service connection in Pipeline is case sensitive.
Even though your ACR name is capitalized, the URL has to be lowercased.
For example:

So we need to use lowercase ACR url in Docker Service Connection.
